# Saving In-Game Currency using as3

Tags: actionscript-3, saving-data, google-cloud-save

I have implemented In-Game Currency in my game. Currently I am saving the number of coins the user can spend using SharedObject. Everything works fine. When the user uninstalls and re-installs the app, all data is lost and the user has to start all over again.

How do I save my current progress? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could have a simple MySQL player database which you would communicate with PHP. It's fairly simple solution and wont take too much effort, but there surely is multiple different third party solutions too. I don't have experience on those, so can't tell which is most simple one.

Comment: **SharedObject** is stored within **File.applicationStorageDirectory** location(https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#applicationStorageDirectory) which is also removed on app uninstallation. In order to have persistent data save, you need... **Option 1**: server solution and a way to identify (obviously, to restore the user's own save, not someone's else) the user, like Google Play auth or FaceBook auth. **Option 2**: like Kaarto said, an independent data storage that will not be removed while uninstalling the app.